# How to access S3 bucket cli without having to log in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, web-hosting

I want to create a bucket that can be accessed by users in certain IP range without having to login. So these users should be able to freely upload files to that bucket without logging in. And I want to access these files from a lambda using the S3 file link provided by my users.

I am trying to first allow anyone to access the bucket without logging in before adding IP restrictions.

---

I made the bucket public with this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-public-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also gave public access via ACL to write to the bucket:

[image: S3 ACL ui]

---

Right now if I try to access the link (https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/my-public-bucket/?region=us-west-2&tab=overview) to the bucket in incognito I get this:

[image]

I thought I could use the static web hosting url (http://my-public-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com) but that's only to host websites.

Is my only option creating a new IAM role and giving its credentials to the users? This is a very bad user experience and I want to avoid it.

Comment: Can you have them use an FTP type application like Cloudberry  or WinSCP instead?  You enter credentials once, then use a file-oriented UI for file transfers.

Comment: I really don't want to move outside aws. Is this not possibe using aws?

Comment: Are you suggesting anonymous file uploads, or that you have a frontend app that should be able to upload without a user having IAM credentials?

Comment: I want to support anonymous file uploads. I thought this was supported but I could not see any documentation on enabling it.

Comment: Don't use ACLs, just use an S3 policy. Your bucket policy, as written, allows unauthenticated users to get all objects in the rqa-testing bucket but it doesn't currently allow them to list the bucket. Yes, you can support unauthenticated uploads to S3 - it's not a great security practice, of course, but you can do it if it's absolutely needed. Note that doing that allows user B to overwrite an object that user A just uploaded.

Comment: Oh! So I need to remove the ACL and add ListBucket permission? And what url will I use? https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/my-public-bucket/?region=us-west-2&tab=overview . And I  tried adding "ListAllMyBuckets" but it's obviously invalid on a bucket. So what action should I add? Adding "s3:ListBucket" gives Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

Comment: @jarmod ^ (can't edit my comment)

Comment: Users cannot use the S3 console to list buckets and manage files without actually being authenticated as AWS users. Unauthenticated users can use a command line tool, such as the awscli, or you're likely going to have to find a UI-based tool (such as Cloudberry) that provides the features you need, or write an application to do this.

Comment: So I will have to create an IAM user and give its login details to the users?

Comment: Re: "Can you have them use an FTP type application like Cloudberry or WinSCP instead?" --    It sounds like you don't realize that many FTP programs can work with S3 buckets as if they have FTP servers.  They show your local file system on the left, the S3 bucket on the right.  Unless you use scripting for program-directed uploads this seems like a nicer UI than using CLI

Comment: Yeah I do get what you mean. But for my use case the CLI is quite enough. @DaveS

Answer (score 1):

The **Amazon S3 management console** requires a lot of permissions to work "correctly", such as the ability to list all buckets, the ability to list buckets, etc.

If your goal is to give specific users access to a bucket, first **consider *HOW* they will be accessing the bucket**. If they will be automating the process, then using the AWS CLI is a good option since it can be easily scripted. Also, only specific permissions are required (eg `PutObject`).

Using the **AWS CLI does require AWS permissions**, which can either come from an IAM User (not recommended for people outside your organization unless you have an on-going relationship with them), or you can use temporary credentials generated by your own back-end app (which would authenticate them, then generate temporary AWS credentials).

If the AWS CLI is too "unfriendly" for these users, then utilities such as CyberDuck can provide a **familiar drag & drop interface to S3**. However, it needs the same credentials as the AWS CLI would use.

You could provide **anonymous access to the bucket** restricted to an IP address range, but they would need to interact via direct POSTs to the bucket, presumably via a website you provide to them. This is because all API calls need to be authenticated.